# What's wrong with numba compilation with using numpy?

Tags: numpy, jit, numba

I cannot compile this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import jit, float64, complex128
import math

@jit(complex128[:](float64,float64[:],float64))
def GaborWavelet(omega, t, Gabor_coef):
    
    c1 = 0.3251520240633*math.sqrt(omega)
    c2 = -0.5*Gabor_coef
    c3 = omega*0.187390625129278
    
    res = np.array(c2*(t * c3)**2, dtype = np.complex128)
    
    res.imag = omega*t
    
    return c1*np.exp(res)
```

It raises:

Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "GaborWavelet" failed type inference due to: No implementation of function Function() found for signature:

array(array(float64, 1d, C), dtype=class(complex128))

There are 2 candidate implementations:
- Of which 2 did not match due to:
Overload in function 'array': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 504.
With argument(s): '(array(float64, 1d, C), dtype=class(complex128))':
Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence

```
res = np.array(c2*(t * c3)**2, dtype = np.complex128)
^
```

What do I wrong?

How to compile this code (with numpy methods inside)?

Answer (score 4):

Numba does not support two of the things you use, but equivalent options:

1. Type conversion via `np.array(arr, dtype=type)`.
   Instead use `arr.astype(type)`.
2. Setting `arr.imag=values` for complex datatypes. Instead use `arr += values*1j`.

The following code works on my machine and should yield equivalent results:

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import jit, float64, complex128
import math

@jit(complex128[:](float64,float64[:],float64))
def GaborWavelet(omega, t, Gabor_coef):

    c1 = 0.3251520240633*math.sqrt(omega)
    c2 = -0.5*Gabor_coef
    c3 = omega*0.187390625129278

    res = (c2*(t * c3)**2).astype(np.complex128)
    res += omega*t*1j

    return c1*np.exp(res)
```